# Summarize a table, delete its data, insert summary into original table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this has to be a simple one but everything I want to do is generic so google terms are difficult to create to get what I want!

Basically I have a table for my data and a job which enters new data every 30 seconds. This data is already grouped by the appropriate fields and also by date.

As there is a huge ammount of data coming in, much of it similar to what is already in the table I want to have the table itself summarised. Obviously one way to do this is to create a second table and every 30 seconds do the following:

```
==> group by on the primary table and insert into secondary table 
==> delete primary table 
==> insert secondary table into primary table 
==> delete secondary table
```

Now I know there is a simpler way of doing this without having to create another table and a bunch of jobs and the associated overhead but I cannot find it using google!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you keep your data and the summary of your data in the same table ? Could you be more precise about the structure of the table ?

I think you should either have two tables (one for the data, the other one for aggregates) or have a 'type' field in your table, saying if it's a simple line of data or the result of an aggregate.

If you choose to have a 'type' field you can do something like

```
INSERT into mytable (a,b,c,type)
    select count(a),MAX(b),c,'aggregate' from mytable 
    where type='line' GROUP BY c

delete from mytable where type='line'
```

Comment: I should have been more specific but your your suggestion will work. I was hoping for something even simpler to be built in so I could run a single command like Summarise my_table group by date, machine, machine_type

Comment: I think such a command doesn't exist because you are not supposed to store aggregates in the same table as the data. Of course I may have missed an easier way to do this.

Comment: I understand, the data coming in every 30 seconds is already an aggregate but I want to merge it with the data in the table. If I left it for the day in a staging table and moved it across only when all the data for the day is complete, it would take up a huge amount of space so I need to constantly aggregate the new data with the existing data